# How to sync dir from a container to a dir from the host?

Tags: docker, vagrant

I'm using vagrant so the container is inside vm. Below is my shell provision:

```
#!/bin/bash
CONFDIR='/apps/hf/hf-container-scripts'
REGISTRY="tutum.co/xxx"
VER_APP="0.1"
NAME=app

cd $CONFDIR
sudo docker login -u xxx -p xxx -e xxx@gmail.com tutum.co
sudo docker build -t $REGISTRY/$NAME:$VER_APP .
sudo docker run -it --rm -v /apps/hf:/hf $REGISTRY/$NAME:$VER_APP
```

Everything runs fine and the image is built. However, the syncing command(the last one) above doesn't seem to work. I checked in the container, `/hf` directory exists and it has files in it.

One other problem also is if I manually execute the syncing command, it succeeds but I can only see the files from host if I `ls /hf`. It seems that docker empties `/hf` and places the files from the host into it. I want it the other way around or better yet, merge them.

Comment: Are you using `vagrant rsync` or just using VirtualBox shared folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's just how volumes work I'm afraid. Basically, a volume is saying, "don't use the container file-system for this directory, instead use this directory from the host".

If you want to copy files out of the container and onto the host, you can use the `docker cp` command.

If you tell us what you're trying to do, perhaps we can suggest a better alternative.